# Zipalign modification

Tags: android, signing

When producing an Android build the android documentation states that you should zipalign only after you [have signed](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html).

But isn't the whole purpose of signing to make sure that your archive is unmodified?

I don't understand how you can sign something, then modify it and it can still be in a signed state.

Comment: In Java only the content is getting signed, not the JAR/APK itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zipalign differs from modifying. It aligns zip header bytes so when your app runs on a device, it starts (unzips in memory) faster and takes less memory comparing to a none-aligned zip. It does not modify files in the archive, so sign would be valid after it.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it, you sign every individual file, not the archive itself. Is that the correct understanding?

Comment: No, APK is like a zip archive, zipalign would align whole archive.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the documentation https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/zipalign says you need to align using zipalign BEFORE signing which makes sense.
I guess you misread the documentation.